# When I refresh row in phpMyAdmin (MAMP), all values disappear

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

I'm having a problem in my phpMyAdmin using MAMP.

Whenever I click 'Edit' to edit a row, if I refresh all values go empty. Then I go back to the table and the row is still there, but every time I view a row and refresh, no matter what database, the values disappear.

I'm not very advanced with phpMyAdmin but I'm assuming that's not supposed to happen.

Any help would be really appreciated.

**Edit**: Thanks to pitchinnate I found the error but have no idea what it means:

'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.

It's referring to this line in get_scripts.js:

```
var global = window[key];
```

Do I just need to update MAMP or something?

Comment: Use a browser that has firebug installed then look at the Console, there is probably an AJAX error.

Comment: What version of phpMyAdmin is it?

Comment: Also what browser are you using? And what version?

Comment: I'm using version 4.1.11. Tried Chrome and FF